# Angular test: why do I get a ReferenceError while attempting to inject a mockService?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using an Angular 14.2.0 project (created with ng cli, no change in tsconfig nor in angular.json).

I'm trying to write a simple test on a component which injects a service UserService.

I use `jasmine.createSpyObj` to mock the service, but as soon as I provide it in the TestBed module, I have this error:

```
 An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UserService' before initialization
```

This is really confusing, since I'm not trying to instantiate the service at all.

I commented the component creation to understand which piece of code is producing the error, and it confirms that the error is definitely triggered by the use of a provider for my mock service.

Here is the code that triggers the error :

```
describe('UserListContainerComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockUserService = 
        jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', [
          'getUsers'
        ]);
    mockUserService.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(profiles));

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UserListContainerComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
});
```

Error disappears as soon as I comment the "provide: UserService" line (but obviously, I won't go far in the component instanciation without it).

BTW, I also tried:

- using a home-made mock object instead of a Jasmine Spy
- using a class (and the useClass property).

In all cases, the error still shows up.
I don't understand why it tries to instanciate the actual service.

Any idea of what I'm missing here ?

PS: I literally emptied my component, including the constructor and any reference to the service, to make sure it's not the cause.
I still have the error with that component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list-container',
  templateUrl: './user-list-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list-container.component.css']
})
export class UserListContainerComponent {
  private _filteredUsers$ = new Subject<Person[]>();
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error states that the problem is in ```afterAll```, yet it is not included in your example. Have you left some code out, or perhaps it is code in a different file that is giving you the issues?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are only 4 spec files in my project and none of them has an afterAll (and all other tests succeed if I just remove the one described above).

Comment: Maybe try making `mockUserService` just a simple object with a `getUsers` method, then use `jasmine.createSpyObj` to spy on `getUsers` in the actual test instead of before `configureTestingModule` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be happening and I can't explain why this error occurs. Can you try the following modification to see if the error goes away? I have noticed that spy objects are always created in the following way.

```
// !! Move declaration here
let mockUserService: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;
beforeEach(async () => {
    // !! Create a new spy object here
    mockUserService = 
        jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>('UserService', [
          'getUsers'
        ]);
    // !! Mock the method here
    mockUserService.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(profiles));
    // !! Same TestBed.configureTestingModule
```

Comment: I just tried, but the error is still happening.
Thanks for the suggestion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I definitely don't consider this as an acceptable solution on the long run, but need to share that I got my test to work by downgrading the TS compiler target to **es5** !

Fortunately, that change can be restricted to the **tsconfig.spec.json** but still... **es5** is now marked as a deprecated target, so any better solution would be welcome.